# How to pass root logger level dynamically in log4j

Tags: java, log4j

Need to pass the root logger dynamically, based on the SIT and etc environment. how to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean you want to override the level defined in the config file?

Comment: yes i done. in log4j xml, i am reading the property file and passing root logger. thanks.